# The local variable n may not have been initialized

Tags: java

```
import View.UI;
public class App {
UI m;    
public static void main(String [] args){
    System.out.println("Hello");
    UI n ;
    n.menu();
}}
```

The UI class is in View,the import is done but in the last expression I get the error  `The local variable n may not have been initialized`.I'm a starter in Java and I don't get it why I'm not allowed to use it this way.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5

Comment: The error was actually self-explanatory. The local variable n was NOT INITIALIZED. Yes, you DECLARED it on that line; but you did not "initialize" it; meaning you did not say what it was equal to before using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are declaring variables/object inside the method in java you need to initialize it.

In most simple term,

In your case its an object which is accessing a method so if you do not initialize it like

```
UI n = new UI();
```

it would give you an NULL pointer exception.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    System.out.println("Hello");
    UI n =AssignUIOBjectHere ;
    n.menu();
}}
```

Method's local `variables` needs to be initialize, before they are using.

Compiler complaining that you are using a variable which is not yet initialized.

As per [language specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5)

> Every variable in a program must have a value before its value is used:

Answer (score 1):

As it is, calling `n.menu()` will cause a `NullPointerException` since you never assign anything to it.

You will need to do something like so: `UI n = new ...` or `UI n = someObject`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create an instance of UI, such as;
UI n = new UI();